# Why my zabbix housekeeper take so long to clean data

Tags: config, zabbix

I got a problem with my housekeeper on one of my server.
The first clean the data in less than 12 minutes and delete 1542939 hist/trends.
The second that has almost the same number of value per second take 7 hours to delete 1244574 hist/trends and i have no idea why ?

can you help me with this point because the two configuration are the same ?

thanks

The two config files are the same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: our housekeeper is working fine. we re on ssd high performance storage: `633:20220124:172633.471 housekeeper [deleted 9583178 hist/trends, 37081 items/triggers, 720 events, 580 problems, 1080 sessions, 0 alarms, 1079 audit, 0 records in 697.724992 sec, idle for 1 hour(s)]`

Comment: The thing is i dont understand, why for the same number of file it dont take the same time to delete the entry ?